# Nginx: logging to syslog

Tags: logging, nginx, configuration, syslog

I need to put Nginx logs to syslog. My Nginx version in 1.6, system - Ubuntu 12.04.
In Nginx config I do:

```
server {
    # some settings here
    access_log  syslog:localhost;
    # and some settings here
}
```

Make a request with curl:

```
curl http://localhost/
```

Get standard Nginx page, but syslog is still empty...

**UPD:** Problem was fixed after uncommenting in rsyslog.conf following lines:

```
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the nature of Syslog. In the documentation[1] you see that the default facility is local7. If you have not set a destination for that facility and created the log file, it will not go anywhere.

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Comment: So I should also add a path to file for according facility to syslog config, shouldn't I? I thought I can do it only with editing Nginx config

Comment: You can change the facility, to an existing one. See your syslog.conf.

Comment: I solved my problem(see UPD section in my question), thanks for your answer - it gave me right direction!